# RestFul API Node.js, Express - error status - response empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am creating a RestFull API in Node.JS that checks if a particular license plate is registered in the database (MySQL), at the end point I just inform the Ex board: (http: // localhost: 3009 / _api_v1 / car / ABC2012 ) and using a get function if this card exists it returns this card in json format, until it is working, but if you enter a card that is not registered for example (http: // localhost: 3009 / _api_v1 / car / WWW3432 )) should return a message err.status (Error ('404 Not Found'), but it is returning an empty array [] and without this message

```
router.get('/:id?', function (req, res, next){

    Node.getNodeBylicensePlate(req.params.id,function(err,rows){
      if(err)
      {
          res.json(err);
      }
      else
      {
          res.json(rows);
      }
    });
});
```

===========================

```
getNodeBylicensePlate:function(licensePlate,callback){

        return db.query("select licensePlate from car where licensePlate=?",[licensePlate],callback);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the mysql query is returning an empty array

```
router.get('/:id?', function (req, res, next){
    Node.getNodeBylicensePlate(req.params.id,function(err,rows){
      if(err) {
          res.json(err);
          return;
      }

      if (!rows.length)  {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Not Found' });
        return;
      }

      res.json(rows);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's because you are only returning an error if there's a true Sql error (Invalid query, timeout, deadlock, etc).

You'll need to interrogate the `rows` variable and if an empty result return a 404:

```
router.get('/:id?', function (req, res, next){

    Node.getNodeBylicensePlate(req.params.id,function(err,rows){
      if(err)
      {
          res.json(err);
      }
      else
      {
          if (!rows || !rows.length) {
             res.status(404);
          }
          else {
             res.json(rows);
          }
      }
    });
});
```